# how to pass parameters from one model to another in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, models

Hi I have two model Company and Feed

company.rb

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :rss_url, :name
  has_many :feeds
end
```

feed.rb

```
class Feed < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :guid, :name, :published_at, :summary, :url
  after_create { |feed| FeedEntry.update_from_feed(feed.feed_url) }
  belongs_to :company

  def self.update_from_feed(rss_url)   ?????
    feed = Feedzirra::Feed.fetch_and_parse(rss_url)   ?????
    add_entries(feed.entries)
  end
end
```

How two take RSS_URL from company to feed ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what `add_entries` does, but if you want to access the `rss_url` of Company inside `Feed`, you can use the association. Define this instance method on your `Feed` class.

```
def do_something
  url = self.company.rss_url
  puts "This feed belongs to a company with the following rss url: #{url}"
end
```